# Problems with ionic back button

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have a problem with the back button of my application.

Initially I thought that the problem was in Cordova, but I have identified that the problem is actually in Ionic.

I found this code while researching for a solution:

```
  // Disable BACK button on home
  $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
    if($state.current.name=="app.home"){
      navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
    else {
      navigator.app.backHistory();
    }
  }, 100);
```

However, it is giving the following error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ionicPlatform is not defined

I am putting that code within a new document called `functionAngular.js` and I add it at the end of the `body` tag. As I must inform this function ?

My problem is that:

> I want my back button to send the user further back in the navigation stack instead of closing the application instantly.

I am grateful for this help.

Comment: Please post functionAugular.js

Comment: In the file is the function described above.

Comment: Please check whether you included $ionicPlatform as a parameter to that function

Comment: In addition, is rightly described as above, there is no longer anything in the document.

Comment: I know not do this, would have as auxiliary me ?

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module('EGLISE')

.run(function($ionicPlatform,$state,$ionicHistory){

 $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function (event) {
    if($state.current.name=="app.home"){
      navigator.app.exitApp();
    }
    else {
       $ionicHistory.backHistory();
    }
  }, 100);

});
```

Please modify your functionAngular.js to the above code.

Comment: I will make a build and tour the result. Only doing this, will operate ?

Comment: It is still not working, not even is grabbing the event.

Comment: Review your response, it seems to me that ha errors.

Comment: my app name is 'EGLISE'

Comment: Uncaught Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'EGLISE' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.

Comment: what is your module name mentioned in app.js? if it is not 'EGLISE', then please replace the module name in functionAngular.js with the one got from app.js.

Comment: There is another place to encounter him module ?

Comment: Inside the file ionic-angular.js has this line:  var IonicModule = angular.module('ionic', ['ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.router']),

Comment: try with 'ionic' in the place of 'EGLISE'

Comment: Worked but I need to give two clicks on the button to return, would like help me in this ?

Comment: It is giving an error in your code in line where describes $ionicHistory.backHistory(); can help me to store ?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you first add $ionicPlatform in controller, and in the first controller loaded, test every state (see below) that the back button should have different actions.

```
    $ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function () {
        if ($state.current.name == " login (example) ") {
            ionic.Platform.exitApp();
        }
        if ($state.current.name == " main menu buttons (example) ") {               
            // Sample message "want to exit the application?" (YES/NO)                         
            if (YES) {
                $ionicViewSwitcher.nextDirection('back');
                $state.go(' ????');
            };
        };
        if ($state.current.name == " order (example) ") {               
            // Sample message "want to exit the order?" (YES/NO)                         
            if (YES) {
                $ionicViewSwitcher.nextDirection('back');
                $state.go(' ????');
            };
        };                        
    }, 100);
```

Comment: I am half layman looks on all this and I am having great difficulty, the other code it not picked up or even the event, would give me some help specifies, where to place and how to place ? We need to press the button of the cell itself it does not exit the application.

Comment: The registerBackButtonAction shouldnt be tested on the phone. In the emulator does works. You are testing the phone?

Comment: Yes I tested at the telephone and the emulator, on both he has not listened to the event and went out of the application.